# C# What are the Advised Coding Practises to place Constant String Literals in Class

Tags: c#, string, coding-style, code-standards

Where is the best place to put string literals within the class? Should they be declared as constant members, should they be referenced in the method (provided the string literal is only ever used once), should they be put in a helper class or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to strings that are displayed to user and require internationalization?

In .NET and Java you can use Resource Files that lets you use a key/value resource file. This has the added advantage of not needing compilation every time you need to change text, and you don't need to be a coder to be able to modify the resource files.

If you're just talking about internal strings that are used (like keys, IDs etc.) then I wouldn't fuss too much about it - some people like "constants.cs", while other like it within the file that is using them, and others like putting each set of constants in their own relevant packages. Just keep it ... Constant.

Comment: Thanks Daryl. I am referring to strings that do not need to be localised.